# cocos2d adwhirl integration: auto click on the ad banner

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, iad, adwhirl

i'm integrating adwhirl (iAd and admob) into my cocos2d game. the current setting is just showing the banner in the game. now i want to remove the banner in my game scene, but when you lose the game,

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [LoseScene scene]];
```

then i add a banner in the lose scene. but i want to auto click on the banner. How to do this? I use the tutorial here: http://emeene.com/2010/10/adwhirl-cocos2d-iphone/
plz help me with code. ( i think it should be a command like touch, equivalent to actual touch inside the banner area. (i will only use it when the banner is successfully loaded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that ad providers generally don't allow you to simulate a user clicking on the ad. The reason is simple: if you, as the programmer, decide that the ad should be clicked, then you would generate costs for ad providers without the user actually being interested in getting more info on the ad.

In other words: allowing programmers to do what you are trying to do would cause false page impressions, and open the doors for fraudulent app behavior.

If instead you meant full-screen ads, then you should look for the documentation about "interstitials". That's what the full-screen ads that need to be dismissed by the user are called in iAd and AdMob.